# Update github summary wth action's results

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd, summary

I would like to modify our the GHE workflow summary with some action's results using `GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY`

Here is how it is organized:

1. From the `web UI` or `gh CLI`, we launch a `generic workflow` which build a matrix based on some module's configuration file.
2. The `generic workflow` calls a `specific workflow` (e.g: build_and_test)
3. The `specific workflow` calls a set of composite `actions` (like build, test and so on).

I would like to build a summary from some `actions`'s results.

I first tried using parameters to "escalate" the workflow layers (action->specific workflow->generic workflow) and then with `GITHUB_ENV`, but it looks that this last option is owned by the file and not the entire mechanic.

Comment: You want the `actions` summary to be shared in the `generic workflow` result, did I understand correctly? It may be possible to generate a [job summary](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-job-summary) for each `specific workflow` step, and upload them as artifacts to download the result in the `generic workflow`.

Comment: Yes you did understand correctly. In fact I would like to create a table to access test results's url + some test result and so on. Do you think it still be "readable" ? Because currently, we use annotation for this and consequently, we are a bit lost into those because we potentially create a lot of annotion.

Comment: Creating a table is interesting, but it will be hard to achieve this using Github Action alone. Do you plan to write a script or something like this to get those data and turn them "readable"?

Comment: Thanks :). I really am a beginner with all this, but I simply though of appending a string to an environnement variable with a the correct format and then send this string to the summary.

Comment: The issue will be to share those environment variables between workflows. Even as string you'll need to use artifacts (or an external API / solution).